# Is "past infinitive" a canonical name in English grammar?

Tags: terminology

An ELL [post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/241040/109190) uses a term "past infinitive"

> If the speaker uses the past infinitive here (to have started) they are setting the temporal focus later than the time the lesson should have started.

I am aware of the concept of past simple, present perfect, etc. I am also aware of the concept of infinitive.

I understand that the "past infinitive" refer to "to have started" in the original discussion. I just did't know the term before, and I googled it. top results link to something like French grammar.

Is "past infinitive" a canonical name in English grammar?

Comment: This isn't even the past to begin with, but the perfect.

Comment: @AeonAkechi Thx, what does "This" refer to?

Comment: @JavaLatte I was trying to say "related to a rule, principle, or law, especially in the Christian Church". Btw, what does "Re" stands for?

Comment: @JavaLatte How about just focus the first half, "related to a rule, principle, or law".

Comment: @AeonAkechi with JavaLatte's help, I guess I got it. You were saying the correct term is "perfect infinitive", rather than "past infinitive", right?

Comment: @AeonAkechi: In some analyses/terminological systems, the perfect can be considered a type of past tense.

Comment: I suppose you could call it the perfect-infinitival, though that is not a 'standard' term. Such clauses are **not** canonical.

Comment: @BillJ Can you explain why you don't think clauses containing perfect infinitival forms are canonical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oxford guide to English grammar, in section 112.2.b, uses the term **perfect to-infinitive**. If you google **past infinitive**, you will find some references, but the majority of sources use the term **perfect infinitive**.